# copy content in linux

Tags: linux, copying

I am totally new to linux. I want to copy jdbc.properties from X-directory to Y-directory. How do I do that? I am in my home directory. So, X and Y both are in home directory. I am doing 
[P4840946@TUS3F01 HOME]$ cp -R /X/jdbc.properties /Y . Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
% pwd
/home/me
% cp X/jdbc.properties Y/
```

Notice where '/' appears.